How to do directional smoothening while cleaning jagged scanned mesh?
i have a 3d scanned mesh model which im struggling to smooth, this 3d model is basically have a extruded profile with sharp areas, which is jagged due to 3d scanned surface, is there any way i can dictate to blender to smooth these areas ? ( ill include blend file)
what im looking is a sculpting method to rapidly fix these jagged areas with out loosing sharpness of my model .
in the blender model below you see that im artificially generating problem and trying to solve the issue but no luck .





